# Ninject fails with NullRef exception if there is a property accessor in interface

Tags: c#, mono, ninject

I've been searching for other relevant posts but I didn't find anything, so here goes...

I have a (super)simple Ninject test that fails with a NullReferenceExcption and I can't find any info on why. It happens if there is a C# simplified property accessor defined in the interface, otherwise it's ok.
If I remove the get; set; functionality it works as expected.

My question is am I simply doing something that shouldn't work - e.g. is this related to th deprecated field injection functionality?

The whole (failing) example is very short:

```
using System;
using Ninject;

namespace NinjectIFPropError
{
    public interface IDummy
    {
        int Number {get;set;}
        void Doit();
    }

    public class DummyClass : IDummy
    {
        public int Number {get;set;}

        public void Doit()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doit");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<IDummy>().To<DummyClass>();

            IDummy id = kernel.Get<IDummy>();
            id.Doit();  
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the default Mono 2.10.5 install on Ubuntu 11.10. Ninject is v2.2.1.0 for .Net 4.0 downloaded from Ninject.org.

Any info would be appreciated.

/A

I'm appending the stack trace as well (pretty long):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.GetParentDefinition (System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, BindingFlags flags) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.GetParentDefinition (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.IsDefined (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo element, System.Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.HasAttribute (System.Reflection.MemberInfo member, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Selection.Heuristics.StandardInjectionHeuristic.ShouldInject (System.Reflection.MemberInfo member) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Selection.Selector+<>c__DisplayClass3.<SelectPropertiesForInjection>b__2 (IInjectionHeuristic h) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[IInjectionHeuristic] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Selection.Selector.<SelectPropertiesForInjection>b__1 (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateWhereIterator>c__Iterator35`1[System.Reflection.PropertyInfo].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Reflection.PropertyInfo].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Reflection.PropertyInfo].AddRange (IEnumerable`1 collection) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Selection.Selector.SelectPropertiesForInjection (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Planning.Strategies.PropertyReflectionStrategy.Execute (IPlan plan) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Planning.Planner+<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetPlan>b__1 (IPlanningStrategy s) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[IPlanningStrategy] (IEnumerable`1 series, System.Action`1 action) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Planning.Planner.GetPlan (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create (IContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.KernelBase.<Resolve>b__7 (IContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateSelectIterator>c__Iterator27`2[Ninject.Activation.IContext,System.Object].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateCastIterator>c__Iterator17`1[NinjectIFPropError.IDummy].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[IDummy] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate, Fallback fallback) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[IDummy] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[IDummy] (IResolutionRoot root, Ninject.Parameters.IParameter[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at NinjectIFPropError.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00018] in /home/roger/Projects/NinjectIFPropError/Main.cs:38 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.GetParentDefinition (System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, BindingFlags flags) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.GetParentDefinition (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.IsDefined (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo element, System.Type attributeType, Boolean inherit) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMemberInfo.HasAttribute (System.Reflection.MemberInfo member, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Selection.Heuristics.StandardInjectionHeuristic.ShouldInject (System.Reflection.MemberInfo member) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Selection.Selector+<>c__DisplayClass3.<SelectPropertiesForInjection>b__2 (IInjectionHeuristic h) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[IInjectionHeuristic] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Selection.Selector.<SelectPropertiesForInjection>b__1 (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateWhereIterator>c__Iterator35`1[System.Reflection.PropertyInfo].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Reflection.PropertyInfo].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Reflection.PropertyInfo].AddRange (IEnumerable`1 collection) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Selection.Selector.SelectPropertiesForInjection (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Planning.Strategies.PropertyReflectionStrategy.Execute (IPlan plan) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Planning.Planner+<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetPlan>b__1 (IPlanningStrategy s) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[IPlanningStrategy] (IEnumerable`1 series, System.Action`1 action) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Planning.Planner.GetPlan (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create (IContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.KernelBase.<Resolve>b__7 (IContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateSelectIterator>c__Iterator27`2[Ninject.Activation.IContext,System.Object].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateCastIterator>c__Iterator17`1[NinjectIFPropError.IDummy].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[IDummy] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate, Fallback fallback) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[IDummy] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[IDummy] (IResolutionRoot root, Ninject.Parameters.IParameter[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at NinjectIFPropError.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00018] in /home/roger/Projects/NinjectIFPropError/Main.cs:38
```

Comment: I just ran your example straight up with no modifications on a Win7 machine using the normal .NET framework and it ran just fine, if that's any hint to you.

Answer (score 6):

You need to make sure you are using the Mono build when running Ninject in a Mono environment.  If you go to the [TeamCity build server](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt243&tab=buildTypeStatusDiv) you can get the artifacts for the Mono 2.0, 3.5, and 4.0 builds. Please try them to see if your issue is resolved.

Comment: Under login form there is small `Log in as guest`.

Comment: I hope the Mono build has the same functionality as the Windows build and is compatible with Windows as well. How am I supposed to deal with Ninject in a project which developers use Windows and Linux? AFAIK, there is no official NuGet package for the Mono build, nor a NuGet target for Mono.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here from a Unity3D application:

As @Ian Davis answered, for mono you should use the mono builds.
For unity in particular I think it should be the mono 2.0 build.

- http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=103530&buildTypeId=bt243&tab=artifacts#!fdjgtbh8re5n,-m7r9mzkc1dh5
- At the login screen, click the small `Log In as Guest` link under the username/password boxes.